# How to create object of type SP.ListItemFormUpdateValue

Tags: 2013, javascript, client-object-model, list-form

How can i instantiate object of type SP.ListItemFormUpdateValue and initialize it to a List field so i can read the field values on client side?

If this is not posible, how can i read a value in a list new item form on a client side after user inputs data before the item is saved in database?

thanks